# Remove duplicates from List<Object> based on condition

Tags: java, list, java-8, set

Starting point:

```
public class Employee {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

I have a list of Employee: `List<Employee> employee;`

Employee examples from the list:

```
{id="1", name="John", age=10}
{id="2", name="Ana", age=12}
{id="3", name="John", age=23}
{id="4", name="John", age=14}
```

Let's assume that `age` is unique.

How can I remove all duplicates from the list based on the `name` property and to keep in the output the entry with the largest `age`?

The output should look like:

```
{id="2", name="Ana", age=12}
{id="3", name="John", age=23}
```

**The way I tried**:

```
HashSet<Object> temp = new HashSet<>();
employee.removeIf(e->!temp.add(e.getName()));
```

..but the this way the first match will be kept in `employee`

```
{id="1", name="John", age=10}
{id="2", name="Ana", age=12}
```

...and I have no idea how to put an another condition here to keep the one with the largest `age`.

Comment: `HashSet<Object>`? is your Employee object comparable? Just make sure the `equals` report objects with same name as equal.

Comment: You should sort the Employee List first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a way that groups elements by `name` and reduces groups by selecting the one with max `age`:

```
List<Employee> uniqueEmployees = employees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName,
                    Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge))))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which returns `[[id=2, name=Ana, age=12], [id=3, name=John, age=23]]` with your test data.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52888845/1876620), here are two variants:

```
Collection<Employee> employeesWithMaxAge = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             Employee::getName,
             Function.identity(),
             BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge))))
    .values();
```

This one uses `Collectors.toMap` to group employees by name, letting `Employee` instances as the values. If there are employees with the same name, the 3rd argument (which is a binary operator), selects the employee that has max age.

The other variant does the same, but doesn't use streams:

```
Map<String, Employee> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // preserves insertion order
employees.forEach(e -> map.merge(
        e.getName(), 
        e, 
        (e1, e2) -> e1.getAge() > e2.getAge() ? e1 : e2));
```

Or, with `BinaryOperator.maxBy`:

```
Map<String, Employee> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // preserves insertion order
employees.forEach(e -> map.merge(
        e.getName(), 
        e, 
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge))));
```

Answer (score 1):

**ernest_k** answer is great but if you maybe want to avoid adding duplicates you can use this:

```
public void addToEmployees(Employee e) {
    Optional<Employee> alreadyAdded = employees.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getName().equals(e.getName())).findFirst();
    if(alreadyAdded.isPresent()) {
        updateAgeIfNeeded(alreadyAdded.get(), e);
    }else {
        employees.add(e);
    }
}

public void updateAgeIfNeeded(Employee alreadyAdded, Employee newlyRequested) {
    if(Integer.valueOf(newlyRequested.getAge()) > Integer.valueOf(alreadyAdded.getAge())) {
        alreadyAdded.setAge(newlyRequested.getAge());
    }
}
```

Just use `addToEmployees` method to add `Employee` to your list.

You can also create class extending `ArrayList` and override `add` method like so and then use your own list :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add values in a `Map<String, Employee>` (where string is name) only if age is greater of equals than the one in the map.